# How to randomize the file names from all files in one folder? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have a folder with many files and I want that all the file names are randomized with the filenames from other files so that file 1 has the name from file 2 but this with more than 100 files.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import random
import os

# Get a list of files
file_names = os.listdir()

tmp_names = [str(i) + ".tmp" for i in range(len(file_names))]

# Renaming to arbitrary filenames to avoid replacing
for old, new in zip(file_names, tmp_names):
    os.replace(old, new) 

# Shuffle the file names
random.shuffle(file_names)

# Randomize
for old, new in zip(tmp_names, file_names):
    os.replace(old, new)
```

Comment: Probably should do an `if old != new:` before the replace for safety in some OSes

Comment: I built it into my script, but there is one problem. How to add exceptions for files, and how to prove that only files with the same expansion will be shuffled?

Comment: @customswitch Expansion?.... Do you mean same extension?

Comment: Yes, I mean the same file extensions.